# Dojo TabContainer vertical scroll or slide

Tags: dojo, scroll, tabcontainer

I am working on tabcontainer which have a large number of tabs, and the tabposition is left,
is there a way to enable a vertical scroll or slide for the tabs?

I searched and only the horizontal slider appear when the tabposition is top

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "tabcontainer" can use an attribute called "controlWidget" which allow you to use your own controller

This attribute may be not supported in version 1.7.2 as it is not in the api documentation